# "Tensor must be from the same graph as Tensor" when calling keras model train_on_batch

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
gen_examples = self.generator.predict([xmal_batch, noise])
```

Generator is a keras model which adds noise to original data and generate new examples

```py
with tf.Session() as sess:         
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())

    saver.restore(sess, PATH)
    print ("load model from:", PATH)

    ymal_batch = sess.run(model.y_pred, feed_dict = {model.x_input: gen_examples})

    self.substitute_detector.train_on_batch(gen_examples, ymal_batch)
```

> ValueError: Tensor("training/Adam/Const:0", shape=(), dtype=int64) must be from 
>   the same graph as Tensor("Adam/iterations:0", shape=(), dtype=resource).

I'm new to Tensorflow and I don't know why there's this error, since `gen_examples` and `ymal_batch` are basically numpy arrays.

It seems like there's new graph created, but I'm so confused.

Comment: hey, did you find the answer? I am facing the same problem